# Simple code for Breadth First Search Java

Tags: java, arraylist, breadth-first-search

I have an ArrayList of arrays like this:

```
[11, 3]
[2, 3]
[0, 3]
[1, 4]
[5, 4]
[5, 7]
[6, 7]
[7, 8]
[8, 9]
[9, 10]
[0, 5]
```

I have to implement the breadth first and go from 0 to 1 by via and print all the values by putting them into a separate array.

result should be: `[0 5 4 1]`

Please someone help me out here. Where to start, and what to do?

Comment: I don't even understand your requirements. Why should the result be `[0 5 4 1]`? What does that result mean? And what does "go from 0 to 1 by via" mean? Via what? What do 0 and 1 represent and how are they related to your arrays and/or values?

Comment: @fillpant. No sir, I am not having even single clue about where to start. All youtube tutorials about BFS are different than my case.

Comment: @Thomas Although it is poorly worded, if you use the nodes (with 0 as a root) you can create a tree. 0-5-4-1 is the correct path from 0 to 1.

Comment: @Thomas. Thanks for your reply Thomas, actually this is a sort of maze in which these values comes from a text file into arraylist. then, starting from 0 I have to connect values or nodes to 1. you can take each value as an joining box I have to go from box0 to top most which will be box1.

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr. yeah. so how can i make a tree or search starting from 0 and then finding its joining values and then going to next array and so on...

Comment: Ah I see, so the arrays basically define the adjacency, i.e. `[1, 4]` means there is an edge between nodes 1 and 4.

Comment: @Thomas. yeah exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple start to this problem. It looks like you do not understand the general idea of what is going on so lets break it down into steps.

1. Graph your "tree".

Use your first set of points to draw what the tree (or maze) looks like. You should clearly see the path from 0-5-4-1.

2. Look into how to do a Breadth-First search. The general pattern is to start at the root and look outwards. I recommend some reading on how to do this properly in theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

*Hint (since I am guessing this is homework):

> If you run it on that set of data, the first few nodes searched should be 0, 3, 4, 2, 11, 4, 7...*

3. Lastly, implement it in Java. There is a number of questions already and tutorials online about how to achieve this. My recommendation is look at some of the related content on this website of look it up online.

Unfortunately if you want to continue using the array you have been given (not recommended) it will be a fairly ineffective search. However, here is some pseudo code to get you started.

```
bfs(starting position)
for each element in the array
    find all elements related (connected) to starting position
    if(connectedNode = endNode)
        end search
    else 
        recursively call this function on the elements found
```

Comment: Thankx bro. I have been reading about it since this morning and now its night here. I finally gave up and posted the question to get some code help from you expert guys. if you can plz.